Google Earth Engine JavaScript API reduceRegion vs. reduceRegions computation efficiency
Context
I often need to calculate zonal statistics in the Google Earth Engine JavaScript API across many features in a feature collection. I usually use the reduceRegion() function and map over the feature collection, to have control of parameters like maxPixels. However, when running a computation speed test (Earth Engine script), reduceRegions() performs better (3x faster) than reduceRegion(). In my understanding however, reduceRegions() maps reduceRegion() over a feature collection under the hood.
Note that re-running the computation in Earth Engine will lead to different computation time, probably because Earth Engine leverages the cached results from the last computation.
Question
What is the difference between the reduceRegion() and reduceRegions() algorithms that leads to different computation times?
